# Message box will not pop up when itis run from the menu. This function is also slow

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, popup

I have two problems.

1) My function `noDateAlert();` is SLOW. Any suggestions to make it take less than 5 seconds? Currently takes 17-30 depending on how many lines it has to check.

2) The error message will not pop up when I run `noDateAlert();` in another function from my custom menu. It works fine when I run it by itself from the script page. It also works fine when run within the other program from the script page.

I'm using this program to warn me if the 3 cells are empty.

When it is enclosed in the other function it is the first thing listed.

Here's the function:

```
function noDateAlert() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sh0 = ss.getSheetByName("Loads");

  // get data from Loads sheet
  var data = sh0.getRange(8,29,53,31).getValues(); 
  var data2 = sh0.getRange(8,3,53,3).getValues();


  for(var i=0; i < 45; i++) {   //Controls how many rows it goes through for posting  //  len = data.length; i < len

  //Only work on loads currently wanting to post 
  if(data2[i][0] == "P-Post"){ 

     //Warn me if all 3 cells in one row are empty/blank
     if(data[i][0] == "" && data[i][1] == "" && data[i][2] == ""){
           Browser.msgBox("Some of the loads you want to post are missing dates. Please check dates and run 'Post Loads' again.");
           return false;
           break;
        };
      };
   }; 
};
```

Comment: Why is `data2` getting 3 columns of data?  The code shown only gets data from index zero.  You could change that to 1 column of data if that's all you need.

Comment: No I need all 3 columns. I have 3 column dates so i can insert up to 3 dates. If they are all blank I need the warning to pop up. If there is a way to look at all 3 as one object that might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your msgbox. And I'll keep on looking at the other problem.

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Some of the loads you want to post are missing dates. Please check dates and run \'Post Loads\' again.');
```

I'm not privy to your data but I doubt that I do things this way.  But since you have access to and knowledge of your data I'll assume that breaking this up in two ranges makes sense.  However, I hope you realize that data2[i][0] is actually column 3 and data[i][0] is actually column 29.  I left the limit for i at 53 since you specified 53 rows in both ranges. But again.  I don't know the detail nor do I have access to the data.  So if this doesn't help, you can change it back.

```
function noDateAlert() 
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sh0=ss.getSheetByName("Loads");
  var data = sh0.getRange(8,29,53,31).getValues(); 
  var data2 = sh0.getRange(8,3,53,3).getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<53;i++) 
  {   
      if(data2[i][0]=="P-Post")
      { 
         if(!data[i][0] && !data[i][1] && !data[i][2])
         {
           SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Some of the loads you want to post are missing dates. Please check dates and run \'Post Loads\' again.');
           return false;
         }
      }
   } 
}
```

Comment: I did try it as 4 && segments and it works about the same as breaking it up into two if statements. If there is no P-Post though there is no sense checking the other 3 columns. I'll check what you have and see how it improves things. thank you!

Comment: i broke i up into two ranges because there is a lot of data in the sheet and I don't want it to have to gather all that data each time. I just need column C and columns AC:AE.

Comment: So I tried SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Some of the loads you want to post are missing dates. Please check dates and run \'Post Loads\' again.'); I get the same problem as before. If I manually run it from the script editor it works. If I run it as a timed trigger or from within a program it doesn't.

Comment: The problem is not the alert command. I just got it to run by changing the data ranges and it run's just fine.  So the problem is either in you code or the data.

Comment: I have data validation in some of the ranges. Could that be the problem?